# Extracting inner generic type of union returning unknown

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to extract the generic type of a union, but I get unknown.
However, if I explicitly try to extract (check code below), it returns the type correctly. Why? And how can I extract the type generically?

```
'use strict';

type  error = {
    tag: 'error',
    error: string
}

type success<T> = {
    tag: 'success',
    value: T
}

type Either<T> =  error | success<T>;

type extractGeneric<Type> = Type extends Either<infer X> ? X : never


type innerType = extractGeneric<Either<number>>; // type is unknown
type innerType2 = Either<number> extends Either<infer X> ? X : never; // type is number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `innerType` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and `innerType2` is not.

That means that they act differently.

Quote from `distributive conditional types` docs:

> If we plug a union type into ToArray, then the conditional type will be applied to each member of that union.

`ToArray` is equivalent of `extractGeneric`

Hence, `extractGeneric` first tries to obtain generic argument from `error` then from `success`. Because `error` does not have generic parameter it returns `unknown`. This is by design

Consider this pseudocode:

```js
type extractGeneric<Type> = Type extends error (unknown) | Type extends success<infer X> ? X | unknown : never
```

In fact we are ended up with `X | unknown`. Because `unknown` is less specific than `X` union of `X | unknown` returns `unknown`.

> How can I extract the type generically?

Just use a part of union which expects generic parameter

```js
type error = {
    tag: 'error',
    error: string
}

type success<T> = {
    tag: 'success',
    value: T
}

type Either<T> = error | success<T>;

type extractGeneric<Type> = Type extends success<infer X> ? X : never

type innerType = extractGeneric<Either<number>>; // number
```

As you might have noticed it does not throw an error since `Either` extends `success`

**OR**

you can just turn off distributivity:

```js
type error = {
    tag: 'error',
    error: string
}

type success<T> = {
    tag: 'success',
    value: T
}

type Either<T> = error | success<T>;

type extractGeneric<Type> = [Type] extends [Either<infer X>] ? X : never

type innerType = extractGeneric<Either<number>>; // number
```

P.S. By convention, all your type aliases should be capitalized.

```js
// bad
type foo = number

// good
type Foo = number
```